# Problems with coordinates and axes in Plot

Tags: plotting

I just solve this system:

```
system := NDSolve[{
    proteinA'[t] == 
     equDiferencial[proteinA[t], 
      activatorRegulation[proteinI[t], kia, proteinA[t], kaa, h], kgA,
       bmA, bpA, \[Gamma]pA, R1[t, 1], R2[t, 1]],
    proteinI'[t] == 
     equDiferencial[proteinI[t], 
      inhibitorRegulation[proteinA[t], kai, h], kgI, bmI, 
      bpI, \[Gamma]pI, R3[t, 1], R4[t, 1]],
    proteinT'[t] == 
     equDiferencial[proteinT[t], 
      targetRegulation[proteinA[t], kat, h], kgT, bmT, 
      bpT, \[Gamma]pT, R5[t, 1], R6[t, 1]],
    proteinA[0] == 100, proteinI[0] == 0, 
    proteinT[0] == 0}, {proteinA[t], proteinI[t], proteinT[t]}, {t, 0,
     6},
   StartingStepSize -> 0.1, 
   Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}, 
   MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]];

# with 
activatorRegulation[inhibitor_, kia_, activator_, kaa_, 
   h_] := (1/(1 + (inhibitor/kia)^h)) ((activator/kaa)^h/(
    1 + (activator/kaa)^h));
inhibitorRegulation[activator_, kai_, h_] := ((activator/kai)^h/(
   1 + (activator/kai)^h));
targetRegulation[activator_, kat_, h_] := ((activator/kat)^h/(
   1 + (activator/kat)^h));
```

And plotted it

```
Plot[Evaluate[{proteinA[t], proteinI[t], proteinT[t]} /. system], {t, 
  0, 6}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  " Stochastic Differential Equation (SDE) of Langevin for A - I ", 
 FrameLabel -> {"time", "molecules"}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Activator", "Inhibitor", "Target"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Gray, Cyan}]
```

And I got this plot:
[image]

The plot does not have numbers in the axes and the option GetCoordinates appears as &Aborted. What is this happening? and how can I change it ?

Comment: Check if you have dynamic updating enabled. In older versions of Mathematica, ticks will not display correctly when dynamic updating is not enabled.

Comment: Your code cannot be executed. You have undefined functions and parameters.